# Thrift Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, thrift, osx-mavericks, thrift-protocol

I cannot, for the life of me, successfully run "gem install thrift", the thing fails when building the gem's native extensions; this is the output:

```
(acib708) ~ -> gem install thrift
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thrift:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/acib708/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:25:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:25:in `<main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for strlcpy() in string.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binary_protocol_accelerated.c
compiling bytes.c
compiling compact_protocol.c
compiling memory_buffer.c
compiling protocol.c
compiling strlcpy.c
                                           ^
```

(...)

```
In file included from strlcpy.c:20:
./strlcpy.h:28:15: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___strlcpy_chk'
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'
  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
  ^
./strlcpy.h:28:15: note: '__builtin___strlcpy_chk' is a builtin with type 'unsigned long (char *, const char *, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:105:3: note: expanded from macro 'strlcpy'
  __builtin___strlcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz (dest))
  ^
4 errors generated.
make: *** [strlcpy.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/acib708/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thrift-0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/acib708/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thrift-0.9.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

I've seen lots of similar errors around the web, but I haven't found the solution. I'm running OS X 10.9, with a fresh rvm/ruby-2.0.0-p247 install. Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

the issue for the moment can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2219

As a temporary fix for folks using gems, you can try setting the #define'ing the _FORTIFY_SOURCE macro to 0 to make strlcpy a function rather than a macro:

```
gem install thrift -- --with-cppflags='-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0'
```

or if you're using bundler, you can set the cflags for thrift locally via:

```
bundle config build.thrift --with-cppflags='-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0'
```

Comment: Also worked for me!  I ran the `bundle config` command and then ran `bundle install` again and it worked great.

Answer (score 8):

The following should install the gem.

```
gem install thrift -- --with-cppflags=\"-Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro\"
```

In bundler, you'll need to do the following until a new ruby release goes out with the fix linked to in the issue above.

`bundle config build.thrift --with-cppflags=\"-Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro\"`

Comment: I'm having problems installing the version 0.11.0 on macOS (Sonoma 14.2.1). Running this command, my problem was solved `gem install thrift -v '0.11.0' -- --with-cppflags="-Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro"`

Comment: I also needed to install these dependencies:
`brew install boost`
`brew install libevent`
`brew install thrift`

Answer (score 7):

On OS 10.9.4 the command below worked for me

```
bundle config build.thrift "--with-cppflags=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0"
```

Answer (score 3):

rather than use a workaround with cppflags I committed a fix which checks for __has_builtin(strlcpy) and if builtins are not available on the system but strlcpy is defined then it uses externs as it previously did. works on os x 10.8, 10.9, centos, ubuntu, ...

Answer (score 1):

Please edit the **~/.bundle/config** file then it looks like this:

```
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__THRIFT: "--with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\""
```

It works for me, thanks.