# Elephant-bird mvn package error

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I have installed hadoop 2.2 in my system. I want to use Elephant-Bird jar. Am getting following error while runnning "mvn package".

Error:

---

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project elephant-bird-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [9,39] error: package org.apache.commons.lang3.builder does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [10,31] error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [11,31] error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [12,31] error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [14,31] error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [15,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.apache.thrift.protocol
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [20,0] error: package org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/core/target/generated-sources/thrift/com/twitter/elephantbird/thrift/test/TestListInList.java:    [42,43] error: cannot find symbol
```

---

I have added below code in pom.xml but still the error exist.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

How can i resolve this error ?

System Configuration

```
Thrift version 0.9.1

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:28+0530)
Maven home: /usr/lib/mvn/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Hadoop 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed Thrift from 0.9.1 to 0.7.0 by downloading from http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.7.0/thrift-0.7.0.tar.gz. Extract and go into the extracted folder. Then typed following commands :

- chmod +x ./configure
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

Check thrift version by typing thrift -version. This should return **"Thrift version 0.7.0"**

Then go to elephant-bird folder and type "mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package"

Note : skip test is used as some tests were failing. Skip test options solved the issue.

Console output :

```
[INFO] Building jar: /usr/lib/hadoop/elephant_bird/examples/target/elephant-bird-examples-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Elephant Bird ..................................... SUCCESS [2.043s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 .......................... SUCCESS [4.277s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................ SUCCESS [16.622s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................ SUCCESS [0.106s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................ SUCCESS [0.462s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout .............................. SUCCESS [5.026s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig ................................. SUCCESS [9.756s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile .............................. SUCCESS [3.745s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene .............................. SUCCESS [3.320s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene .......................... SUCCESS [1.736s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................ SUCCESS [6.653s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.204s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 15 01:28:31 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 64M/386M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT : 
Pig was throwing error while compiling load statement for JsonLoader as json-simple-1.1.1.jar was not found. Google for the jar, you can find it easily. ( Cannot post link due to less than 10 reputation)

and there was an error thrown while launching pig job regarding hadoop-compat. Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/elephantbird/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat/4.4/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.4.jar
(Also found in < elephant-bird-folder-path >/hadoop-compat/target/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.4-SNAPSHOT.jar

)

register 4 Jars to use Elephant-Bird plugin in Pig.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror might help if you are getting ruby error while executing "make".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962715/rvm-can-not-install-gem-thrift-on-ubuntu-11-10 might help if you are still stuck with ruby gem error. The issue has been fixed in 0.8 version of THRIFT. Download the 0.8 thrift from archive site link: http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz