# Error building elephant-bird-pig

Tags: maven, hadoop, build, apache-pig, elephantbird

Upon request in comment, this is the last dump of

```
mvn clean install -U -Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0 -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.repo.local=localrepo
```

http://textuploader.com/ay4a8

---

**Update #2** I checked the online repo mentioned in the error

```
Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com
```

http://maven.twttr.com/com/twitter/elephant-bird/

It is empty. What should I do?

---

**Update #1** It is not duplicate of Force update.

I tried

```
mvn clean install -U -Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0 -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.repo.local=localrepo
```

which produced the same error, except that it starts downloading files again and it takes longer to get to the error.

---

**Original Content**

I have been working hard (**12 hours+**) trying to install elephant-bird locally in my `$HOME` in a shared research-purpose cluster. after **12 hours+** of hard work, I am still lost in the ocean. Any kind man who cares to pull me up to a boat?

I have strived to install the correct versions of `protocol-buffers` (version 2.5.0) and `thrift` (version 0.7.0).

Executing version check gives:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
$ thrift -version
Thrift version 0.7.0
```

Ok, all looks fine. download elephant-bird by

```
git clone git://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird.git
```

CD into the directory and run

```
mvn -Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0 -Dmaven.test.skip=true package
```

`-Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0` is advised by the [official github](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird#version-compatibility) of elephant-bird for I am running a non-default version of `protocol-buffers`. `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` is advised by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181345/elephant-bird-mvn-package-error) because I did fail some tests during elephant-bird-core build.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Elephant Bird Pig 4.11-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Elephant Bird ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.643 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................. SUCCESS [  2.514 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................. SUCCESS [ 25.494 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 ........................... SUCCESS [  2.650 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Crunch ............................... SUCCESS [  3.218 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................. SUCCESS [  2.342 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig .................................. FAILURE [  0.238 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.748 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-10T20:02:11-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/964M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project elephant-bird-pig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :elephant-bird-pig
```

Well, let's run the same command with `-X`:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Elephant Bird Pig 4.11-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
....
Skipping >>>>>>>
....
[DEBUG]       commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1:provided
[DEBUG]       org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:provided
[DEBUG]          org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided
[DEBUG]       org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided
[DEBUG]       tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.12:provided
[DEBUG]       tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.12:provided
[DEBUG]       org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.14:provided
[DEBUG]       org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:jar:6.1.14:provided
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:provided
[DEBUG]          ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:test (scope managed from compile by com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird:4.11-SNAPSHOT)
[DEBUG]       commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:provided
[DEBUG]       net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.7.1:provided
[DEBUG]       org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.14:provided
[DEBUG]       net.sf.kosmosfs:kfs:jar:0.3:provided
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test (scope managed from compile by com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird:4.11-SNAPSHOT) (version managed from 4.8.1 by com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird:4.11-SNAPSHOT)
[DEBUG]       hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:provided
[DEBUG]       oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
[DEBUG]       org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.5.3:provided
[DEBUG]          com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:provided
[DEBUG]          org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.3.2:provided
[DEBUG]    org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.4:provided
[DEBUG]       org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:provided
[DEBUG]          org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:provided
[DEBUG]          antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[DEBUG]       org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.4:provided
[DEBUG]    joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:provided
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:provided
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:provided
[DEBUG]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:test
[DEBUG]    org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.1:test
[DEBUG]       cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:4.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/huip/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:4.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:4.11-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Elephant Bird ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.661 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................. SUCCESS [  1.462 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................. SUCCESS [ 13.790 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 ........................... SUCCESS [  0.397 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Crunch ............................... SUCCESS [  0.533 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................. SUCCESS [  0.567 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig .................................. FAILURE [  0.215 s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.260 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-10T20:17:39-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/964M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project elephant-bird-pig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project elephant-bird-pig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-pig:jar:4.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:192)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.twitter.elephantbird:elephant-bird-core:jar:tests:4.11-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.twttr.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of twitter has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :elephant-bird-pig
```

What now?

Comment: @Tunaki your comment replied at the top. Thank you for bringing this up. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace you had when you ran Maven with the `-U` option?

Comment: @Tunaki dump uploaded. Thank you for helping out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: OK, it seems like a bug of `elephant-bird`, you should raise an issue at their GitHub.

Comment: @Tunaki Issue at github filed. I hope they can fix this soon because a part of my research depends on being able to parse irregular JSON in PIG...

Comment: @Tunaki A superman from twitter Github solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that solved this problem is:

```
mvn clean install -U -Dprotobuf.version=2.5.0 -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.repo.local=localrepo
```

The reference is this:

[Maven skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727536/maven-skip-tests)

D*mn it, Maven...Now I feel like I was so dump...